# Adding data under price for each product in product listing

Tags: magento2, theme

I want to add some data under the price for each product in a product listing. To show an example I would like to add static data where the blue lines are:

[image]

I've made modifications to `frontend/company/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/listing.phtml` as this seemed to be the correct place to make the edits. But, after making changes and flushing cache, the product listings are not updated.

The template helpers I enabled do not seem to show where this template is stored.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I was overriding the wrong file. The file I should have been overriding is: `frontend/company/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`